# Cross domain work around with IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, cross-domain, iis-7.5

I am building an application that is ready for release however I have come up against the cross domain scripting problem within my ajax calls.

I am using IIS7.5 and I have the following applications setup

Marketing Application - 'www.mydomain.com' - Used as the marketing website and for registering for a new business.I have a rule that forces any non www. to be www

Business Application - 'https://newbusiness.mydomain.com' - Used to access their services they have subscribed to

API Application - 'https://newbusiness.mydomain.com/api/.......' - Used for business application to do crud operations

API application is an application running under the business application. Containing a number of secured methods and some anonymous ones.

With jquery I am having trouble from my marketing application trying to call the api application. Currently if I want to call the api from my marketing site I am doing something like 'https://api.mydomain.com/api/whatevermethod' because it is cross domain it fails.

Is there anyway that I can somehow map 'https://api.mydomain.com/api/whatevermethod' to be just 'https://mydomain.com/api/whatevermethod' as this would get me around the cross domain problem.

Comment: I don't think it's cross domain issue as Jquery ajax can request any data from any url as long as the web services allows outside callers.  is your www rule only on the www.mydomain.com site or on iis as a whole.  If it's on IIS then https://newbusiness.mydomain.com/api/ is probably being redirected to https://www.newbusiness.mydomain.com/api/.  When you debug the post form jquery in a chrome history debugging tab or firebug in firefox what is the status and error of the ajax call?

Comment: Hi Try to add this line to your web.config files. It enables Cross-domain Ajax Requests. <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow cross domain calls in the IIS. You can do this by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

ex:

in root web.config

```
<system.webserver>       
   <httpprotocol>
     <customheaders>
       <add name="access-control-allow-origin" value="*" />  
       <add name="access-control-allow-headers" value="content-type" />
     </customheaders>
    </httpprotocol>
 </system.webserver>
```

taken from [here](http://tipila.com/tips/83/allow-cross-domain-javascript-calls-in-iis-7)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you also got an error 500 from Amila's answer, here's what the whole web.config file content should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="access-control-allow-origin" value="*" />
                <add name="access-control-allow-headers" value="content-type" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```